# How to add multiple records at a single click?

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2017

I am programming a new software in visual studio 2017 (C#) for an art association for helping them in registering the details of the students that are about to participate in their contest. I made a windows form like this:[image: form]
when I click on the add button after entering details [image: detail] in the text boxes, combo boxes and date time picker, the data grid view must be updated as shown like this: [image: The date of program and participating item of the participant must be entered in the table as four records each for each date and item without changing other details.].I made a try with this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pARTICIPATING_ITEMComboBox.Text != "--")
        {
            rEG_IDTableAdapter.Insert(nAME_OF_PARTICIPANTTextBox.Text, cLASSTextBox.Text, sCHOOL_NAMETextBox.Text, pHONE_NUMBER_OF_PARENTTextBox.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dATE_OF_PROGRAMDateTimePicker.Text), pARTICIPATING_ITEMComboBox.Text, " ", " ");
        };
        if (comboBox1.Text != "--")
        {
            rEG_IDTableAdapter.Insert(nAME_OF_PARTICIPANTTextBox.Text, cLASSTextBox.Text, sCHOOL_NAMETextBox.Text, pHONE_NUMBER_OF_PARENTTextBox.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text), comboBox1.Text, " ", " ");
        };
        if (comboBox2.Text != "--")
        {
            rEG_IDTableAdapter.Insert(nAME_OF_PARTICIPANTTextBox.Text, cLASSTextBox.Text, sCHOOL_NAMETextBox.Text, pHONE_NUMBER_OF_PARENTTextBox.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Text), comboBox2.Text, " ", " ");
        };
        if (comboBox3.Text != "--")
        {
            rEG_IDTableAdapter.Insert(nAME_OF_PARTICIPANTTextBox.Text, cLASSTextBox.Text, sCHOOL_NAMETextBox.Text, pHONE_NUMBER_OF_PARENTTextBox.Text, Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker3.Text), comboBox3.Text, " ", " ");
        };
```

but this didn't work as I wished. Instead it entered the details: Registration number, name of participant, class, school name, phone number of parent and the first date and the first column Like [image: this] i.e. other details entered in the second, third and fourth date and item columns didn't get entered into the data grid view

> Note:
>   The database is created in Access 2016 and was inserted into the form

:

Comment: I thought table adapter INSERT is to add data to the underlying source table. Maybe you want AddRow https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/csharp/csharp-datagridview-add-row. Why use C#? If you are building Access db, why not Access/VBA as GUI?

Comment: Can each participation item have different date? Limited to 4 items? Why have the intermediate step of sending data to GridView?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it should be just 1 if condition like

```
if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3)
{
   insert(...);
   insert(...);
   ...
}
```

You used 4 comboboxes for same participation item collection. Instead you can use a combobox to select item and a listbox to pass selected items to it. After that with a foreach loop you can add listbox items to db.

it should look something like

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(item in listbox.items)
    {
        insert(name.text,class.text,item.text,......);
    }
}
```

Also it'd be better if you divide this table into 2 separate tables. For detailed info you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/database-normalization-normal-forms/)!

Comment: Listbox okay unless each participation item can have different program date as shown in example but that is probably a typo. Splitting table reasonable.

Comment: correct. I've seen the date input just now :) one more input for date can be used with participation item combobox and listbox. listbox can hold both date and participation item.